# what mechanisms can i use to transfer a resultset to another view page?

Tags: php

how do i transfer the `$rs` to a new page resultdetails.php?

processenterpin.php

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    //query to fetch the concerned result
    $query = "select * from result_header where RegNo = $regnumber && d_level = $details && d_sem = $d_sem";
    $rs = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    //find a way and send rs to a new page then vomit the resultset in that new page.
}
```

I know about sessions. I was wondering if there is another way.

retrieve `$rs` in resultdetails.php and use while loop to print it there

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)){
    //
}
```

Comment: Looking at that snippet, looks like the query is using user submitted data so it's vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. When plugging data into a query, ***ALWAYS*** use prepared statements, irrespective of the source of the data.

Comment: If you're redirecting the users to other pages where you want the result, do the query on those pages. If you include those php-files, then it shouldn't be an issue (if they are in the same scope). But before you continue, you should follow the previous comments suggestions and use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use function for passing result one page to another.

STEP 1. create db.php

```
      <?php 

      $servername = "localhost";
      $username = "root";
      $password = "root";
      $dbname = "test";

      // Create connection
      $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);

      // Check connection
      if ($conn->connect_error) {
          die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
      } 
      //echo "Connected successfully";

      ?>
```

STEP 2. create  processenterpin.php

```
        <?php

        require_once('db.php');

        function process($conn){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM result_header";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        return   $result;   

        }

        ?>
```

STEP 3. create resultdetails.php

```
            <?php 

            require_once('processenterpin.php');

            $result=process($conn);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    // output data of each row
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["name"]. "<br>";
                    }
                } else {
                        echo "0 results";
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: your idea is wonderful. I will look prepared statement like you guys mentioned. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

In which file you have to used just add below code after variable declare.

As @spacePhoenix said ALWAYS use prepared statements.

`include('resultdetails.php');`

Like :

```
$rs = "Test variable";

include('resultdetails.php');
```

Now in **resultdetails.php** file you can used $rs variable.